# Why i get this error , when trying to connect Firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

Trying to connect my project to firebase, with this command:

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

and got this error:

```
-alias : The term '-alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystor ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-alias:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you tried to run a shell command that starts with "-alias" without making it part of the keytool command.  If you are using the windows command shell, that backslash might not be continuing the command.  Just remove it and run it all on one line:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding, when i use youre command , i also get error, but different :
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:917)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:419)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:412)

Comment: That's a different problem.  I can't tell you where your keystore file lives, or if you even have one at all.